# Anylogic: printing the outputs to excel

Tags: java, output, anylogic

I have some datasets which I want to print to excel after each run of simulation. 
Dataset name: `Arrival1`,
Excel file name: `ExcelOutputs`,
The code that I wrote: `excelOutputs.writeDataSet(this.Arrival1, "Tabelle1", 1, 1);`

Data in dataset:

```
0   0

300 15

480 24

700 35



900 45

1,180   59

1,360   68

1,520   76

1,740   87

1,980   99

2,180   109

2,460   123

2,700   135

2,900   145

3,340   167

3,500   175
```

Data I get in the excel sheet:

```
0   0

340 17

580 29

700 35

900 45

1200    60

1420    71

1600    80

1800    90

2020    101

2200    110


2340    117

2520    126

2620    131

2820    141

3000    150

3220    161

3360    168
```

Totally different numbers and I don't know where they come from. There is no other dataset with these numbers and the excel sheet is initially empty.

Can someone please help me! Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I have trucks and each time they arrive simulation writes the arrival time to the data set. Before the run ends data are sent to excel with the code "excelOutputs.writeDataSet(this.Arrival1, "Tabelle1", 1, 1);" . I have too many codes but this is the only one related :) Which part should I post? Do you have something in mind more specific?

Comment: looks like you are writing to Excel at a different point in the simulation than you expect. Double-check it is written at the end of the simulation only.

Comment: I wrote the code in the main section "on destroy" which means code starts when simulation ends or am I wrong?.  And also tried to write the code in a function and an event element. Same result :(